# Getting an error while configuring the maven project : org.testng.eclipse.maven.MavenTestNGLaunchConfigurationProvider.getClasspath

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium, testng, pom.xml

I have created one maven project and now with the help of testNG i am running one code but getting below error

> org.testng.eclipse.maven.MavenTestNGLaunchConfigurationProvider.getClasspath(Lorg/eclipse/debug/core/ILaunchConfiguration;)Ljava/util/List;

POM.xml file :

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.newmaventest
    com.newmaventest.selenium
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    demo for maven
    demo for maven
    
        src/main/resources/testng.xml
    
    
        
            org.testng
            testng
            6.8
            test
        
    
    
        
            
                org.apache.maven.plugins
                maven-compiler-plugin
                3.0
                
                    1.8
                    1.6
                    1.6
                
            
            
                org.apache.maven.plugins
                maven-surefire-plugin
                2.17
                
                    
                        ${suiteXmlFile}

Can someone help ??

Comment: Please, provide full text of the error and sample of the pom.xml file that is related to testNG.

Comment: Error is : "An internal error occurred during: "Launching DemoMaven".
org.testng.eclipse.maven.MavenTestNGLaunchConfigurationProvider.getClasspath(Lorg/eclipse/debug/core/ILaunchConfiguration;)Ljava/util/List;"

Comment: @vaibhavumale copy your pom.xml and past here in your question.